# Scraping data from website with dynamic login parameters and CAPTCHA

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, recaptcha

I am trying to scrape data from a website that requires authentication through a login page. The login page is protected by CAPTCHA, and the website uses JavaScript-based encryption to generate dynamic login parameters, such as the username and password hash.

I have attempted to use Python's requests library along with a session to handle cookies, but I'm facing challenges with bypassing the CAPTCHA and handling the dynamic login parameters.

I've inspected the login page source code and noticed the JavaScript encryption, but I'm not sure how to extract the login credentials programmatically.

Is there any way to automate the CAPTCHA solving process or to extract the necessary login parameters to bypass the CAPTCHA and login successfully? How can I proceed with scraping the data from the website after logging in?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, code examples, or libraries that can help me tackle this issue and successfully scrape the data I need.

Thank you in advance!

I tried to scrape data from a website that requires authentication through a login page. The login page is protected by CAPTCHA, and the website uses JavaScript-based encryption to generate dynamic login parameters, such as the username and password hash.

To handle the login and maintain the session across requests, I used Python's requests library along with a session object. I attempted to extract the dynamic login parameters by inspecting the login page source code, but the JavaScript encryption made it difficult to directly extract the login credentials programmatically.

Next, I investigated automating the CAPTCHA solving process using external services, but I couldn't find a reliable and cost-effective solution for this task.

When running my script, I expected it to successfully log in by bypassing the CAPTCHA and using the dynamically generated login parameters. I wanted to be able to access the data available at "https://example.com/data" after a successful login.

However, the CAPTCHA challenge prevented my script from logging in automatically, and I couldn't find a way to extract the necessary login parameters programmatically. As a result, my scraping attempts failed, and I couldn't access the desired data.

I'm now seeking guidance, code examples, or recommendations for libraries or tools that can help me overcome the CAPTCHA and dynamic parameter challenges, and successfully scrape the data I need from the website.

Comment: Recommendation questions are expressly off-topic. Aside from that, you only provided a set of requirements and then left it to the Community to solve, without showing any work of your own. Please read [ask], as well as how to create a [mcve].

Comment: The reason the site uses CAPCHA and dynamic login is to specifically stop the kind of scraping you're trying to do.  Even if you figure out a way around it, they will likely change it in the near future to make it impossible again.